# Inherit from a built-in class, can't change args of __init__

Tags: python, class, date, python-2.7, python-datetime

I make a class with `date` objects inheritance, but I can't change arguments which should be give to `__init__`.

```
>>> class Foo(date):
...  def __init__(self,y,m=0,d=0):
...     date.__init__(self,y,m,d)
... 
>>> Foo(1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Required argument 'day' (pos 3) not found
```

I already try to use `super`...

If someone know if we can change builtin objects args or the way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date class is a *immutable* object, so you need to override the [`__new__()` static method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead:

```
class Foo(date):
    def __new__(cls, year, month=1, day=1):
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, year, month, day)
```

Note that you need to set the month and day to *1* at least, 0 is not a permissible value for the `month` and `day` arguments.

Using `__new__` works:

```
>>> class Foo(date):
...     def __new__(cls, year, month=1, day=1):
...         return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, year, month, day)
... 
>>> Foo(2013)
Foo(2013, 1, 1)
```